# A form with filtering

Tags: django

I'm trying to set some filtering for a query through a form but I don't really know how to build it.

So I want to filter by "recruitment", "game" and/or "platforme". The problem is that I don't really know how to build it in my views.py.

template.html

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <select name="recruitment" onchange=this.form.submit();>
        <option disabled {%if form.recruitment == Null%}selected{%endif%}>Recrutement</option>
        <option value="all" {%if form.recruitment == "all"%}selected{%endif%}>Tout</option>
        <option value="open" {%if form.recruitment == "open"%}selected{%endif%}>Ouvert</option>
        <option value="close" {%if form.recruitment == "close"%}selected{%endif%}>Fermé</option>
    </select>

    <select name="plateform" onchange=this.form.submit();>
        <option disabled {%if form.plateform == Null%}selected{%endif%}>Plateforme</option>

        <option value="all" {%if form.plateform == "all"%}selected{%endif%}>Toutes</option>
        {%for plateform in plateform%}
        <option value="{{plateform.guid}}" {%if form.plateform == plateform.guid%}selected{%endif%}>{{plateform.name}}</option>
        {%endfor%}

    </select>

    <select name="game" onchange=this.form.submit();>
        <option disabled {%if form.game == Null%}selected{%endif%}>Jeu</option>
        <option value="all" {%if form.game == "all"%}selected{%endif%}>Tous</option>

        {%for game in game%}
            <option value="{{game.guid}}" {%if form.game == game.guid%}selected{%endif%}>{{game.title}}</option>
        {%endfor%}

    </select>

</form>
```

views.py

```
def view_watch_teams(request):
    media = settings.MEDIA

    try:
        myteam = Team.objects.get(owner=request.user)
    except:
        pass

    team = Team.objects.all()
    game = Games.objects.all()
    plateform = Plateform.objects.all()

    if request.POST:
        form = request.POST
```

My query should be something like this :

```
result = Relation.objects.filter(recruitment=form['recruitment'], on_game=form['game'], on_plateform=form['plateform'])
```

This kind of query only work if all filters are set. So, what is the correct synthax to make a query more dynamic ?

Thank you for your help and please ask me if I wasn't clear !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage the fact that QuerySet filtering can be chained like so:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(field_1=val_1).filter(field_2=val_2)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(field_1=val_1, field_2=val_2)
```

So you can do:

```
result = Relation.objects.all()
if request.POST:
    recruitment = request.POST.get('recruitment', None)
    if recruitment:
        result = result.filter(recruitment=recruitment)
    game = request.POST.get('game', None)
    if game:
        result = result.filter(on_game=game)
    plateform = request.POST.get('plateform', None)
    if plateform:
        result = result.filter(on_plateform=plateform)
```

If you want to simplify your code, save some maintenance headaches and learn Django along the way, you could replace your hand-crafted form with a Django form.

Django forms have several advantages: mainly Django generates the HTML, populating items in select fields and checkbox groups, validates data if needed (showing some neat error messages to the user), and automatically converts GET/POST data to the right Python objects.

There is a [very good tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) on the Django project's website. Part 4 is about Django forms, however it is worthwhile going through the full tutorial if you haven't already.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for taking so long for this answer.